# RelativeLayout, ScrollView and navigation bar at bottom

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout, navigationbar

What I want to do is, make layout like this:

Title

Date

Long text with scrolling

Navigation bar stick to the bottom

Well I have done everything, however there is a little problem with scrolling. I want only to scroll text. Title and date should be stick to the top, and nav bar to the bottom of activity. And yes, it works, but my nav bar overlaps text :/

I tried everything, there is one solution I found, set fixed height for Scrollview, but this will not work on every devices well, isn't it? I probably could do some calculation in code, and on it change height, but I would like to stay in XML.

Any one have any suggestions?

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feed_title"
                style="@style/h1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feed_info"
                style="@style/h2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/feed_fav_ico"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_fav_off" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollY="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feed_text"
            style="@style/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Loren ipsum full tekst" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Buttons -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_to_article"
        style="@style/button_screen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/feed_show_full" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_feed"
            style="@style/button_screen"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_up" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_feed"
            style="@style/button_screen"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/feed_share" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_feed"
            style="@style/button_screen"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/feed_delete" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev_feed"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_arrow_down" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- ~Buttons -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the things I have changed:

- Moved top layout to bottom
- Gave bottom layout name `android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"`
- Gave top layout a name `android:id="@+id/top_layout"` (Not necessary just for clarity)
- Now top layout will have these properties:

  `android:layout_above="@id/bottom_layout"`

  `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

  The first one is to make top layout anchored above bottom layout.
  Second one is to align top edge of top layout to parent's top. Which in this case is    RelativeLayout.
- Now bottom layout will have these properties:

  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

  It will tell that bottom edge of bottom layout matches with bottom edge of parent (which is RelativeLayout)

Below is the fully working layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Buttons -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/go_to_article"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Feed full" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_feed"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_feed"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="share" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_feed"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="delete" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev_feed"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!-- ~Buttons -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feed_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/feed_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/feed_fav_ico"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollY="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/feed_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/long_test" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working! I tried something similar, but I didn't get my buttons at the top of xml code. Once again, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to put a weight to the scroll layout ?

```
LinearLayout
- LinearLayout
-- Title
-- Date
- ScrollView layout_weigth=1
-- TextView
- LinearLayout
-- Button
-- Button
-- Button
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I am trying with a lot of changes in the code, but your solution is more simply and easy.

Answer (score 1):

Drag the bottom edge of the LinearLayout (lets call it l1) holding your text and align it to the top edge of the linear layout holding your navigation bar (let's call it l2). So that the AbsoluteLayout.above on l1 is equal to l2.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/l1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/l2">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Jonas says, but to give you a litte more, make sure you fill in the other stuff.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="fill-parent">

    <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       put your title and things in here
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1">  <!-- this makes it not overlap the layout(navbar) below-->
       put your title and things in here
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       put your nav bar stuff in here
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you do not set the layout_weight, the scrollview will actually push the navbar out off the bottom of the screen in this configuration.  It has something to do with how the space for layouts is reserved, I'm not completely sure why, but adding weight delays the reservation till later.
Since the scrollview is filling the parent but still is part of the linear layout, the layout will make sure to accomodate your lower navbar, and unlike the Relative Layout there will be no overlap.